# Can't seems to inherit a protected variable

Tags: c++, class, c++11

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<algorithm> 
using namespace std;

class A
{
protected: 
int x,y;
public:
    A():x(0),y(0){}
    A(double vx, double vy):x(vx), y(vy){}
~A(){}
};
class B: public A
protected:
    double ct;
public:
    B(): A(0,0), ct(0){}
    B(double x, double y, double ctin): A(x,y), ct(ctin){} 
    B calculate(B &v3,A &v2);
    ~B(){}
};
    B B::calculate(B &v4,A &v3)
    {

    x = v4.x*v3.x;


    B temp_R(x,y,ct);
    return temp_R;
    }
```

I am trying to access the first component of v3 which is class A, but the code will not compile, the error messages on the

```
    v3.x;
```

states: "protected member"A::x" is not accessible through a "A" pointer or object.

I thought x and y are inherited from class A to class B, so why is it not possible to access them ?

Comment: Protected member _function_? o.O

Comment: Mate there are other unrelated problems with this code. Post your _actual_ MCVE please, not some snippet you invented in the question submission box.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry just protected member :P

Comment: `class A {` and then a constructor of `base(double, double)`? That's quite some unresolved issues yes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, ok, let me shorten my code so its easier to understand.

Comment: @haavee that is a typo, i changed it now

Comment: `int x, y;` as data members and then in `base(double vx, double vy) x( vx ), y( vy ) {}` ...?

Comment: It's still not right. You don't even _have_ a `V3` member. Post an MCVE as I instructed before.

Comment: `v3` is argument of type `A` to function `calculate()`, if I read that correctly.

Comment: @haavee: Look at `B`'s ctor-initialiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `B` can access protected members of an `A`. But it's the fact that you're going *through* `v3` that makes it essentially irrelevant that this attempt is made from within a member function of `B`. It's `v3` trying to make the access, not `B::calculate`, and `v3` is not a `B&`.

> `[C++11: 11.4/1]:` *[..]* All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression (5.2.5). **In this case, the class of the object expression shall be `C` or a class derived from `C`.**

… followed by a bunch of examples showing exactly your problem.